# How can I get the real DOM in complete browser environment by using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test something like layout using Jest and Enzyme. But Jest uses JSDOM to simulate the real browser environment.

I can only use Jest in this old project. How can I do it?

Here are some descriptions in JSDOM: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#unimplemented-parts-of-the-web-platform

Comment: You'd need a Jest environment that uses a real browser. E.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-browser; although that seems to have been inactive for a while, you could take inspiration from it. There's other discussion: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/139.

Comment: [Jest puppeteer](https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer) may also be interesting